# An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source - happening in nested ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

This given page shows all cities for a particular state.  I am displaying a ListView within a ListView.  The outer ListView shows a listing of cities.  The inner ListView shows all notes attached to each particular city.

Everything loads up properly.  I can add a note, which gets added to the database.  However, after adding a note, clicking the scroll bar in the NotesListView causes the exception:

> An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source

I understand the problem...the listing of notes attached to the ListView becomes out of sync, after I add a note to the city.Notes property in the viewmodel...  But how do I force this ListView to refresh?

Here is my XAML (edited for brevity):

```
<ListView x:Name="CityListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CityDetails, Mode=OneWay}">
<!--City Name and other city details. go here-->
   <ListView  x:Name="NotesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Note}" />
</ListView>
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock Text="Add Note:" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Note, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
  <Button Content="ADD NOTE" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddNoteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

</StackPanel>
</ListView>
```

---

Here is the AddNote() method in the ViewModel that is hooked into the AddNoteCommand:

```
Protected _stateService As IStateService
Protected _state As State

Protected Sub OnAddNote(city As City)
        Dim note As Note = Nothing

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.Note) Then
            note = New Note() With {
                .Note = Me.Note,
                .NoteDate = DateTime.Now,
            }

            city.Notes.Add(note)

            _stateService.SaveExistingState(_state)
            ' this saves the note, since _state contains:
            ' Property Cities As ICollection(Of City)
            ' and the city object passed into this method belongs to that collection...

            RaisePropertyChanged(Function() city.Notes)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# I solved this with:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<Note>(item => city.Notes.Add(item)),
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    note);
```