# ListBox "An ItemsControl isinconsistent with its items source"

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an ListBox which should show some data which will be changed over time.

it works well for a random amount of time, till suddenly an exception is thrown which i can't catch.

let me explain how my application works:

1. I track some Data (own Thread)
2. I show these "tracks" in my ListBox (own Thread)
3. I'm tracking more data
4. I show there new "tracks" also in my ListBox.
5. continue with 3.

The exception orrcures in 3. or 4.

Sometimes it is thrown when iam getting new data (not changing any view or anything) and sometimes it is thrown when the view is updated.

the updating of the ListBox has an own Thread which runs all the time: and just does this:

```
TrackedProcessList.ItemsSource = null;
TrackedProcessList.ItemsSource = this.applicationTracker.trackings;
```

The data tracking also runs in an own Thread and generated new data.

i've read these stackoverflow-threads but they dont have an solution for me:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336750/upgrading-to-net-4-5-an-itemscontrol-is-inconsistent-with-its-items-source
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470621/an-itemscontrol-is-inconsistent-with-its-items-source-happening-in-nested-list
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137213/wpf-listview-inside-grid-scrolling-error-an-itemscontrol-is-inconsistent-with
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692939/how-can-you-share-a-resource-between-listbox-item-instances
```

I also dont know what you maybe need to solve my question, so can you please write me what i need to post

Comment: why not setting the itemssource once with an ObservableCollection<T> and just update this source collection?

Comment: I had an issue like this because the thread was updating the binding too fast and it couldn't keep up (race condition)... I think in the end I used something similar to the following. http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux

Comment: YEs the thread which updates the view is faster than the other.

Comment: Do you use an ObservableCollection for the trackings?